# Gaussian integral evaluation

Tags: probability, normal-distribution

Asked a question to evaluate the Gaussian Integral,

$$\dfrac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}} \int_{-\infty}^\infty x^2 \exp(-x^2/2) dx  $$

using the the following approximation,

$J=\Bbb E[X^2] \sim J_N = 1/N \sum_1^NX_n^2 $

where $x_n \sim N(0, 1)$

Examin $J_N$ for different values of $N$ and plot an error graph (difference between exact and numerical values)

I can simulate and generate the approximations but I am stuck at getting the exact value to compare to. As far as I am aware there are no analytical solutions for gaussian integrals. The other way I can generate comparable numbers is to go use numerical integration techniques but those are approximate values too.

Any help will be greatly appreciated!

Comment: You get $-\infty$ with -\infty

Comment: Hi, that isn't working when I use it in limits of integration symbol. int_\infty^-\infty

Comment: You need braces around multicharacter super/subscripts

Comment: ...and braces around arguments of square roots - I think you probably mean \sqrt{2\pi} not \sqrt2\pi

Answer (score 2):

$$I(a)=\int_{-\infty}^\infty e^{-ax^2}dx\iff-I'(a)=\int_{-\infty}^\infty x^2\cdot e^{-ax^2}dx$$ Now, since we already know that $I(1)=\sqrt\pi$, it is trivial to show, by a simple change in variable, that $I(a)=\sqrt{\dfrac\pi a}$ , in which case our integral is simply $-\dfrac{I'\Big(\tfrac12\Big)}{\sqrt{2\pi}}$ . For more information on this topic, see [here](http://fy.chalmers.se/~tfkhj/FeynmanIntegration.pdf).

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:** integrate by parts:$$
x^2\exp (-x^2/2) = x\times x\exp (-x^2/2)
$$

details:
You get
$$
\int_{-\infty}^\infty x^2\exp (-x^2/2) dx =
[x\times -\exp (-x^2/2)]_{-\infty}^\infty 
- \int_{-\infty}^\infty 1\times -\exp (-x^2/2) dx \\
= \int_{-\infty}^\infty \exp (-x^2/2) dx
=\sqrt{2\pi}
$$

---

More generally,
$$
\int_{-\infty}^\infty x^{s+2}\exp (-x^2/2) dx =
(s+1)\int_{-\infty}^\infty x^{s}\exp (-x^2/2) dx 
$$

Comment: A much shorter route using the same amount of information is to note that the derivative of a standard normal density is simply $-x$ times the standard normal density.

Comment: are you saying that writing $\int uv' = uv - \int u'v$ is *much longer* that $(uv)' = u'v + uv'$?

Answer (score 0):

The object that you have there is essentially the definition of the variance of a standard normal, which equals one.

Comment: it does not adress the question of the computation of this variance.

Comment: The variance is given by the definition of a standard normal in the same way that you assume the value of the integral to be known.

Comment: If the integral resolves to $\sqrt{2\pi}$ then the result of the whole expression is 1. This is essentially the CDF of the normal distribution over + and - $\infty$ and that should be 1. Does that sound right?